# Symfony3 - "Unrecognized field" exception when I want to pull entries based on the value of a Many-to-One relation property

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I want to display records from an entity, but only records that have the loginID value equal to the current user's ID. In the Events entity, loginid is a many-to-one property.
I have the following Events entity:

```
namespace Vendor\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Events
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="events")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Events
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="EventName", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $eventname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Location", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $location;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="StartDate", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $startdate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="EndDate", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $enddate;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Status", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="eventID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $eventid;



    /**
     * Set eventname
     *
     * @param string $eventname
     *
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setEventname($eventname)
    {
        $this->eventname = $eventname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get eventname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEventname()
    {
        return $this->eventname;
    }

    /**
     * Set location
     *
     * @param string $location
     *
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setLocation($location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get location
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }

    /**
     * Set startdate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $startdate
     *
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setStartdate($startdate)
    {
        $this->startdate = $startdate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get startdate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getStartdate()
    {
        return $this->startdate;
    }

    /**
     * Set enddate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $enddate
     *
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setEnddate($enddate)
    {
        $this->enddate = $enddate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get enddate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getEnddate()
    {
        return $this->enddate;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param boolean $status
     *
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status=true;
    }

    /**
     * Get eventid
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getEventid()
    {
        return $this->eventid;
    }

    /**
     * Get web path to upload directory.
     * 
     * @return string
     * Relative path.
     */
    protected function getUploadPath()
    {
        return 'uploads/eventCovers';
    }

    /**
     * Get absolute Path.
     * 
     * @return string
     * Absolute path.
     */
    protected function getUploadAbsolutePath()
    {
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/' . $this->getUploadPath();
    }

    /**
     * Get web path to a cover.
     * 
     * @return null|string
     * Relative path.
     */
    public function getCoverWeb()
    {
        return NULL === $this->getCover()
                ? NULL
                : $this->getUploadPath() . '/' . $this->getCover();
    }

    /**
     * Get web path on disk to a cover.
     * 
     * @return null|string
     * Absolute path.
     */
    public function getCoverAbsolute()
    {
        return NULL === $this->getCover()
                ? NULL
                : $this->getUploadAbsolutePathPath() . '/' . $this->getCover();
    }

    /**
     * Set validation for max file size of 2 MB.
     * 
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="2M")
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * Sets file.
     * 
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = NULL) 
    {
        $this->file =  $file;
    }

    /**
     * Get file.
     * 
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Upload a cover file.
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        //file property can be empty
        if (NULL === $this->getFile()){
            return;
        }
        $filename=$this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();

        //move the uploaded file to the target directory using the original name
        $this->getFile()->move(
                $this->getUploadAbsolutePath(),
                $filename);

        //set the cover
        $this->setCover($filename);

        //cleanup
        $this->setFile();
    }

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="Cover", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cover;


    /**
     * Set cover
     *
     * @param string $cover
     *
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setCover($cover)
    {
        $this->cover = $cover;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cover
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCover()
    {
        return $this->cover;
    }
    /**
     * @var \Vendor\MyBundle\Entity\Logins
     */
    private $loginid;

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\MyBundle\Entity\WishList
     */
    private $wishlistid;


    /**
     * Set loginid
     *
     * @param \Vendor\MyBundle\Entity\Logins $loginid
     *
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setLoginid(\Vendor\MyBundle\Entity\Logins $loginid = null)
    {
        $this->loginid = $loginid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get loginid
     *
     * @return \Vendor\MyBundle\Entity\Logins
     */
    public function getLoginid()
    {
        return $this->loginid;
    }

    /**
     * Set wishlistid
     *
     * @param \Vendor\MyBundle\Entity\WishList $wishlistid
     *
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setWishlistid(\Vendor\MyBundle\Entity\WishList $wishlistid = null)
    {
        $this->wishlistid = $wishlistid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get wishlistid
     *
     * @return \Vendor\MyBundle\Entity\WishList
     */
    public function getWishlistid()
    {
        return $this->wishlistid;
    }
}
```

and the following indexAction in my controller:

```
namespace Vendor\MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Vendor\MyBundle\Entity\Events;
use Vendor\MyBundle\Form\EventsType;

/**
 * Events controller.
 *
 * @Route("/sec/events")
 */
class EventsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all Events entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="sec_events_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $events = $em->getRepository('VendorMyBundle:Events')->findBy(array('loginid' => $user->getLoginid()));

        return $this->render('events/index.html.twig', array(
            'events' => $events,
        ));
    }
}
```

However I am thrown the error: *Unrecognized field: loginid* even though that is the name of the field/property in the Events class. 
I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619071/doctrine2-findby-relationship-object-triggers-string-conversion-error) and I do have the code used as it says in there. 
What am I missing?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Little advice - organize your properties first and method second in your classes. It's better, readable and you'll appreciate it in the future.

Comment: Thanks, good point. I always lose them when I get back to that class. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some ORM definition for `$loginid` and because of that there is no column loginid in your events table.

I assume you want to have OneToMany or ManyToMany association to `...\Entity\Logins`, so you have to define that association according to this: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thanks! <br>
As for OneToMany, I can't add it, and I don't need it as the target property in the target entity is an ID property and it won't allow me to add that option in the annotations, right?

Comment: Simply said - if you don't define ORM annotation for property, it's invisible for doctrine and this property will not be persisted into DB (doesn't matter if simple datatype or association). Then when you want to get loginid within VendorMyBundle:Events repo, there isn't any... You have to options - 1) define some association according to your needs, 2) if you don't want association you have to set $loginid manually, but in stat case, it has to be same type as $id in Logins class