# SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer, Doctrine parameter conversion

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Morning guys,
I have two database that are linked, the tables are `User` and `Theme`, have in mind im not that familliar with php and symfony framework.
a Theme is linked to a User :

```
/src/Entity/Theme.php
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="published")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
   private $user;
```

I'm trying to setup a function that would display all the Theme written by this User based of his lastname, from what i understood  `@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="published")` makes sure my theme isnt only linked by the `user_id` but the user entity.

In my `ThemeController.php` my function is set up this way :

```
/**
     * @Route("/theme/show/{lastname}", name="theme_created_by")
     * 0@param User $ThemeByUser
     */
    public function userThemes(User $ThemeByUser){
        $html =  $this->twig->render('theme/index.html.twig', [
            'themes' => $this->themeRepository->findBy(
                ['User' => $ThemeByUser], ['created_at' => 'DESC']),
        ]);
        return new Response($html);
    }
```

It seems like the query made by Doctrine isn't going thru i get this error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2, t0.created_at AS created_at_3, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_4, t0.user_id AS user_id_5 FROM theme t0 WHERE t0.id = ?' with params ["Roland"]:

SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: "Roland"
```

Which mean Doctrine is expecting a int as a parameter but it is receiving a string. While reading the documentation it seems like the parameters are converted to match anything in the data. Maybe im dont fully understand how it works, just need a little guidance.
thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doctrine2 findBy relationship object triggers string conversion error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619071/doctrine2-findby-relationship-object-triggers-string-conversion-error)

Comment: @DarkBee unfortunately no :/

Comment: Well it seems you can't filter by `user` directly so u'd need to filter on `userId` rather than the object

Comment: yeah but when i use userId i only get when result what im trying to do is to get everything that matches that userId.

Comment: Yeah, but that is a whole other question than what you've asked here?

Comment: What im trying to achieve with my function is to fetch and return every Theme thats associated to that User bu using the lastname attribute, when i pass the userid as a parameters i only get one Theme not all of them .

Comment: You should post another question if this one is resolved... [ask]

Comment: Lol its not resolved, i dont think you understood what im trying to say, maybe i shoudl edit the question.

Comment: Sure I do, but you said "when i pass the userid as a parameters i only get one Theme not all of them", so you are not getting the initial error anymore of your initial question.

Comment: @DarkBee i ended up fixing it by switching the value im passing in the route parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know how and why but in my twig file that rendering the function :

```
<p class="media-body pb-3 mb-0  small lh-125 border-bottom border-gray">
        <strong class="text-gray-dark">Autheur : </strong>
        <a href="{{ path('theme_created_by', {'lastname': theme.user.lastname}) }}">
             {{ theme.user.lastname }}
        </a>
        <br/>
        <a href="{{ path( 'theme_show', {'id' : theme.id} ) }}">
            <strong>{{ theme.name }}</strong><br/>
        </a>
```

i replace that path line with :

```
<a href="{{ path('theme_created_by', {'username': theme.user.username}) }}">
             {{ theme.user.lastname }}
        </a>
```

changed the paramaters passed in my route too :       with `username` `@Route("/themes/by/{username}", name="theme_created_by")`
now it works..